# How to assign specific integer to individual character in word?

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python so I hope someone can point me in the right direction with my question.

I want to assign a specific numeric value (integer) to a character/letter in a word (i.e. given input).

For example:

My input is ‘vase’

```
v= 5
a= 2
s= 7
e= 1
```

So now I want to calculate the “word value” by for example addition, multiplication or division or something (e.g. from ‘vase’ to the total word value, which is an integer).

When I google , I keep finding dictionary examples, but they all seem to work from the idea that a=1, b=2, c=3 etc.

How would I be able to assign self chosen values to individual characters and then calculate with these numbers?

Edit: I should have been more clear. I want to calculate values based on the complete word. So I want to set up values for individual letters which can be used to transform any string input (in this case ‘vase’) into a final value per word.

Comment: You can create your own dict: `x = {a: 2, e: 1, s: 7, v: 5}`

Comment: `my_dict = dict(a=6, b=-1, c=42, ...}`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question and what you are trying to do. If I run the maths based on the number proviuded I see

```
>>> 5+2+7+1%2
15
>>>
```

If I assign the values to the characters v a s e as you show and use the characters I get the same answer

```
>>>
>>> v=5
>>> a=2
>>> s=7
>>> e=1
>>> word_val = v+a+s+e%2
>>> print(word_val)
15
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry, I should have been more clear. I want to calculate values based on the complete word. 

So I want to set up values for individual letters which can be used to transform any string input (in this case ‘vase’) into a final value per word.

Answer (score 0):

Like the first comment said, make your own dictionary. This is what it will look like, try to run this code:

```
import random

i = input().strip()
d = {}
for c in i:
    d[c] = random.randint(0,26) 

print(d)


# Functions on the word, suppose add
sum = 0
for c in i:
    sum = sum + d[c]

print(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this will assign random integers and I want to decide myself (for the entire alphabet) what specific integer is assigned.

Comment: Yeah, that just was to give you an example, you can and will have to build your own dict.  Just replace the line 3-4 in my code with Like this. ` d= {'a': 1, 'b': 4 ...}` and then the rest stays the same/